# GPUImage render to OpenGL ES texture does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0, gpuimage

I would like to render a video in an `OpenGL ES` texture so that I can apply this texture to a 3D surface in my iOS program. To do that I'm using `GPUImage`, but it does not work, no texture seems to be loaded in the output.

Here is the .h code :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

#import "GPUImage.h"

@interface ViewController : GLKViewController <GPUImageTextureOutputDelegate>
{
    GLuint texture;
    GPUImageMovie* movie;
    GPUImageTextureOutput *output;


    GPUImagePixellateFilter* pixellateFilter;
}

@end
```

And here are parts of the.m file :

Init

```
- (void)setupGL
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    [self loadShaders];

    _vertexArrayBuff = generateSphere(0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 10, &_arraySize);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _arraySize * sizeof(GLfloat), _vertexArrayBuff, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, BUFFER_OFFSET(24));

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

    NSString* fileStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileStr];
    movie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:fileUrl];

    output = [[GPUImageTextureOutput alloc] init];
    output.delegate = self;

    pixellateFilter = [[GPUImagePixellateFilter alloc] init];

    [movie addTarget:pixellateFilter];
    [pixellateFilter addTarget:output];

    [movie startProcessing];
}
```

Render

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    // Render the object again with ES2
    glUseProgram(_program);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTUTRE], 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, _arraySize / 8);
}
```

Delegate

```
- (void)newFrameReadyFromTextureOutput:(GPUImageTextureOutput *)callbackTextureOutput;
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        texture = callbackTextureOutput.texture;
    });
}
```

I tried to manually load a texture and display it and it worked so the shaders and texture coordinates are not the issue.

But when I try to set the texture with `GPUImage` it does not work any more, my texture is not displayed, instead I have a black surface.

Does anyone know what I did wrong? I followed the `CubeExample` from `GPUImage` but it does not work.

I really need some help now

Thank you!

PS: I'm targeting iOS 6.1 and I'm using XCode 4.6.2

**EDIT**

Here is the code of the function called at beginning :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2 sharegroup:[[[GPUImageContext sharedImageProcessingContext] context] sharegroup]];

    if (!self.context) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = self.context;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

    [self setupGL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing one critical part of the CubeExample sample code. You need to use a share group to get textures created in GPUImage's OpenGL ES context to appear in your view's OpenGL ES context.

In the CubeExample, I'm not using GLKit, so I create a context for my CAEAGLLayer-hosting view using the following code:

```
    context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2 sharegroup:[[[GPUImageContext sharedImageProcessingContext] context] sharegroup]];
```

This grabs the share group used by GPUImage's image processing OpenGL ES context and uses that as a share group for the rendering context for my view.

I haven't done much work with GLKit myself (I've preferred lower-level OpenGL ES, mainly out of habit), but I believe you set up the OpenGL ES context for your GLKView at some point. You could insert the GPUImage share group at that point, or before you do any GPUImage setup or work, you could use the `-useSharegroup:` method on GPUImageContext's sharedImageProcessingContext to go the other way and set GPUImage to use your view's context's share group.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I used a sharegroup (i edited my post), I just forgot to show you the code doing this. So it still does not work :(

Comment: @FabienHenon - Is this with a live camera source or movie file? If movie file, is this on the device or in the Simulator? There's a known bug with playing movies in the Simulator right now.

Comment: It's a movie from the simulator. It's working when I use AVFundation directly but not when I use GPUImage

Comment: @FabienHenon - Try running it on an actual device. Again, there's a known bug in the framework around playing movies in the Simulator, but they do work on actual iOS hardware.

Comment: Ok, I can't try on a device for the moment but I believe you then. Thank you! (don't know if I should set this thread as solved)